# How to connect HTML to Phpadmin database?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, database-connection

Am currently working on a website(html 5) that calculate the expenses for the user, after the calculation, user has to save it as report for future purposes. So i wanna know if there is anyway to connect my website(html5) to database using phpadmin.

thankyou

Comment: Which Database? Be specific

Comment: HTML 5 is a living standard. Just name your requirements with the bodies that govern it and then see what they come up with. And btw. the current version of HTML is 5.1 not 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

html5 doesn't connect to SQL (phpmyadmin), but php does :)

html5 is for delivering static documents. To do things such as connecting to databases, you need a server side language like php.

html5 generally means javascript and modern html features. Neither of these things have anything to do with PHP. However, you can write php **inside** your html5 web page, and connect to a database from there.

How exactly you would go about doing this depends on what OS you are running, but if you want to start using php and SQL together with phpmyadmin, you'll need to setup an apache server, and install php and mysql.

A full tutorial on it is out of the scope of a stack overflow post, but I suggest researching LAMP, XAMPP, and WAMP keywords. By installing these, depending on your operating system, you should be able to start connecting php scripts with mysql and using phpmyadmin to simplify the process.

There are plenty tutorials on getting php up and running with databases, just use google.

Good luck :)

Maybe these will be helpful:

http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/486 (for linux)

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp (once you get started)

Comment: this is the exact answer.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 is just a static document, You cannot access a server-side databases from a web browser without server side scripts.